# How to extract hour from unix timestamp?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I'm using Spring JPA. And need to extract hour from `begin_time` `BIGINT` field . Values look like this

```
1547654400000    
1547568000000
1547654400000
```

Here is what I tried

```
 @Query("select extract(hour from (s.beginTime/1000)) from TestTable s") 
 public List<Integer> testQuery() { 
 // implementation 
 }
```

But it always returns null.

Java has a method System.currentTimeMillis() . Therefore there must be a method within spring JPA to extract hour from unix timestamp.

How to extract hour from unix timestamp

Comment: Can you add full code of class which is used testQuery method?

Comment: That is not JPQL you post, so it would not work anyway (unless you have some secret `nativeQuery` flag set elsewhere)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if beginTime is unix timestamp, you try `extract(hour from FROM_UNIXTIME(s.last_login) )`,
hope i can help you.

Answer (score 3):

`HOUR(FROM_UNIXTIME(1547654400000/1000))` --> `8`

1. Divide by 1000 to get from milliseconds, to "unixtime".
2. Convert to a time format.
3. Extract the part you need.  (This could be done with `MID()` or other string manipulation, too.)

Caution:  This will get the "hour" associated with whatever timezone is baked into the value.

Perhaps this is what you wanted:

`FLOOR(1547654400000/(1000*3600))%24`, on the other hand, gives you `16`, the "hour" that is in the value.

Think of it this way:  Divide by the parts below "hour" (milliseconds and seconds-per-hour), then go modulo the number of hours per day (24).